# How to select a div id using a variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var input = document.getElementById('newlist');
for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
  var $form = $(document.getElementById("input.files.item(i).name-edit-form"));
  }
```

to be clear, input.files.item(i).name is the var and I'm trying to append "edit-form" to the value.  I think because that wasn't made clear, my question was never answered.

I think the question I'm trying to ask is how do I properly use a jquery var inside a jquery selector in my example?

Comment: I think you mean to do ``$(`#${input.files.item(i).name-edit-form}`)``.

Comment: @Masood Please do not edit code in questions. You could be removing the very reason the question is asked!

Comment: @HereticMonkey I've seen `$(document.getElementById(id))` a few times today on SO - I wonder if there's some new dodgy source/tutorial that's suggesting this for use with jquery.

Comment: `input.files.item(i).name-edit-form` doesn't look like an `id` to me - only use getElementBy*Id* for IDs.

Comment: @freedomn-m I've seen everything done with/to/on top of jQuery. Nothing surprises me any more :).

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you are mixing vanilla JS with jQuery. You should pick one. I created an example that depends on as much jQuery as necessary below.

Please review the docs for [`<input type="file">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file)  over at MDN. You were using `input.files.item(i)` when it should just be `input.files[i]`.

If you are requesting to loop over all forms that match the selector:

> `form[id^="-edit-form"]`

You could try the following:

```js
$('#newlist').on('change', function(e) {
  $.each(this.files, function(index, file) {
    var $form = $(`#${file.name}-edit-form`);
    console.log(`Selecting form: #${file.name}-edit-form`);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="newlist" multiple />
```

**Caveat:** If the file that you selected has a file extension or spaces, you may need to clean up the name to point it to the correct form ID.